# Count word on the page

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

How to scrap any site and search for the given word and displays how many times it occurred

```
class LinkedinScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "linked"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.linkedin.com/']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'linkedin.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: That looks okay so far - what is your exact problem with this code?

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: if word can be in any tag then you can use `"string".find(word, start)` in loop  (and changing `start`) to find all occurrences. Or maybe with regex you could find or occurences and use `len()` to count them in the list.

Comment: you can also use `response.body.count(word)` but it will count even if `word` is part other bigger word - ie. it will count `cat` in `catalog`. So regex can be better.

Comment: example: `"cat catalog cattering".count('cat')` gives 3 cats - so it is not good if you want only one `cat`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with `response.body` to find all occurrances in any places

ie.

```
 import re 

 r = re.findall('\\bcat\\b', "cat catalog cattering") 
 print(len(r), 'cat(s)')
```

Gives `"1 cat(s)"`, not `"3 cat(s)"`

If you need word only in some tags then you use first `response.css()`, `response.xpath()`, etc.

---

**EDIT:**

Example which shows how to use

```
 re.findall(pattern, response.text)
```

but it can find text inside tag too.

It also shows how to use

```
response.css('body').re(pattern)
```

It counts `'view'`, `'\\bviews\\b'` and `'\d+ views'` on `Stackoverflow` and display first three elements

You can run it without creating project.

```
import scrapy
import re

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        for pattern in ['view', '\\bviews\\b', '\d+ views']:
            print('>>> pattern:', pattern)

            result = re.findall(pattern, response.text) 
            print('>>>          re:', len(result), result[0:3])

            result = response.css('body').re(pattern)
            print('>>> response.re:', len(result), result[0:3])

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: see example in answer