# how to get count of matched words in google.com using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

If I gave a word  to the scrapy application. It has to search in google and print the count of the matched words. Don’t hardcode the word in the application  it should take from the console .

```
import scrapy


class GogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gogle'
    allowed_domains = ['google.co.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr/']

    def parse(self, response):
```

Comment: on Stackoverflow you have to show your code and error message.

Comment: You get `HTML` in `response.body` which is normal string so you can use standard string functions or regex to search words.

Comment: [how to run scrapy with arguments](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments)

Comment: see link - it shows that you can run scrapy in console with own argument ie. `-a word=Hello` and later you have to get this word in `__init__` in spider.

Comment: BTW: scrapy was created to run it without interactive action - so you start it with parameters, it runs and you wait or go sleep.

Comment: you have code in link - but if you really need it than use standard `input()` to get word

Comment: maybe you should find tutorial and learn basis. I can copy+paste code from link and you will have your code.

Answer (score 0):

As in [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments)

```
import scrapy


class GogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'gogle'

    allowed_domains = ['google.co.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr/']

    def __init__(self, word=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GogleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.word = word

    def parse(self, response):
        print("word:", self.word)
```

And now you can run it in console as

```
scrapy crawl gogle -a word=electronics
```

and you get word `"electronics"` in `parse()` in `self.word`

Comment: where do you have code which count it ? do you display result or save in file ? maybe create new question.

Comment: scrapy doesn't have special methods to count words - you have to do it on your own

Comment: please, see your previous question - [Count word on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793932/count-word-on-the-page)

Comment: scrapy can give you HTML as standard string and then you can use standard string functions or regex to search words.

Comment: BTW: see module w3lib and [w3lib.html.remove_tags()](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.html.remove_tags) - it can remove all tags and then you get only text on page. It is installed with `scrapy`.

Comment: I have not visited FB for several months - currently I spend time only on StackOverflow

Comment: BTW: in [NLTK tutorial](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html) you can see "Dealing with HTML" and it uses `BeautifulSoup(...).get_text()` to get text without tags.

Comment: no, I can't. You already have all in previous question: [Count word on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793932/count-word-on-the-page)

Answer (score -1):

```
import scrapy
import re


class GogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'gogle'
    allowed_domains = ['google.co.in']
    start_urls = ['https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr/']

    def __init__(self, word=None):
        super(GogleSpider, self).__init__()
        self.word = word

    def parse(self, response):
        string=response.xpath('//div[@class="sbqs_c"]/text()').extract()
        string=''.join(string)
        print(len(re.findall(self.word, string.lower())))
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not forum. It is place for answer/solution, not for question. If you have question then use button "Ask Question"

Comment: do you get expected result ? if not then it is not correct code.

Comment: I see two mistakes. 1. url https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr/ loads main page without search results - so there is no elements to count.

Comment: 2. Google use JavaScript to add elements to page but `scrapy` doesn't run JavaScript. But Google can recognize if "browser" can run JavaScript and sends page which doesn't need JavaScript but it has different tags, classes, etc. When I turn off JavaScript in browser then I don't see `class="sbqs_c` in page with search results.

Comment: BTW: to get page with search result for word "electronics" you can use `https://www.google.co.in/search?q=electronics`

Comment: you should say this in question at start - with all details - maybe even with screenshot which show which words you need. And all would be easier. But with current question it looks like totally different problem.

Comment: It is new question so you have to put all again, or at least you have to put link to previous question with explanation why you add this link. There is so many question so I don't remeber questions which I saw one hour ago.